# unable to make clickable text in wordpress home page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to design a wordpress website with `freshlife` theme:

I have created a post with the following code :

```
<li><a href="http://google.com" class='external'>Pre-order Here</a></li>
```

This post is working fine for individual post but when I see this post on home page then it does not show clickable link.

Live demo can be seen at the link

http://savemoneydeals.in/

in the first post `pre-order here` is not clickable while we open the post the text is clickable.

How can we make the text clickable on home page also ?

Comment: When you inspect this element at your homepage you can see it never renders `<li><a>` tags.

Comment: how it can be rendered

Comment: how are you putting the  content in the home page? from admin panel or inside php file?

Comment: from admin panel by creating a new post

Comment: Can you post home page post calling and print code?